# Vite proxy config failing

Tags: vuejs3, vite

I'm migrating a Vue 2 application to Vue 3, and am switching from Vue CLI to Vite.  I'm having trouble configuring Vite to proxy back-end requests to the back-end.

In the Vue 2 version of the app (using Vue CLI), we have a `vue.config.js` as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: "/app/",
  devServer: {
    disableHostCheck: true,
    proxy: {
      "^/": {
        target: "https://my-back-end:8080",
        toProxy: true,
        secure: false
      }
    }
  },
  lintOnSave: false,
  configureWebpack: {
    devtool: 'source-map'
  }
};
```

And this works fine.

But for the Vue 3 version of the app (which uses Vite), I used a similar configuration for `vite.config.js`:

```
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    port: 3000,
    base: '/app/',
    proxy: {
      "^/": {
        target: "https://my-back-end:8080",
        toProxy: true,
        secure: false,
      }
    }
  },
});
```

And this does not work.  What seems to be happening here is that all requests are being proxied to the back-end, including the ones intended for the app (or UI) itself (which should be handled by the dev server).

(Our API has all requests beginning with path `/app/*` going to the app (UI), and all the rest going to the back-end.  However, the recommended configuration seems to have requests with path `/api/` or somesuch going the back-end, and all the rest going to the UI; our system is reversed from this.)

I've played around with all kinds of options, and have gone over the Vite docs and `node-http-proxy` docs with no success.  Does anyone have any suggestions as to what to try next?